# Как реализовать нумерацию букв по их позиции в алфавите по отношению к другим буквам из строки?

Tags: c

Как можно реализовать нумерацию букв по их позиции в алфавите по отношению к другим буквам из строки?
Например слово "ПРИВЕТ".

```
П Р И В Е Т
4 5 3 1 2 6
```

По задумке программа должна проверять положение чисел в строке, введенной пользователем, и отталкиваясь от результатов , менять порядок цифр в целочисленном массиве.Пробовал сортировкой пузырьком - как я не пытался, выдает не то...

Вот мой код,вроде все правильно,но в ответ выводится 67891011 . Почему?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char min='я',arr[7]="лекция";
    int i,j,mass[6],u=1;
for(j=0;j<6;j++)
    {
        min='я';
    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
{
if(arr[i] < min)    
    {min=arr[i];}
}

if(min==arr[0])
{

    arr[0]='я';
    mass[0]=я;
u++;
}   
if(min==arr[1])
{
    mass[1]=u;
    arr[1]='я';
    u++;
}   
if(min==arr[2])
{

    mass[2]=u;
    arr[2]='я';
u++;
}       
    if(min==arr[3])
{
    arr[3]='я';
    mass[3]=u;
u++;

}   
    if(min==arr[4])
{
    mass[4]=u;
    arr[4]='я';
u++;
}   
    if(min==arr[5])
{
    mass[5]=u;
    arr[5]='я';
    u++;
}   



}




    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
    printf("%i",mass[i]);
}  

}
```

Comment: Вам надо сделать массив индексов букв в строке и сортировать его, только не по величине индекса, а по значению буквы, которую он адресует. После сортировки выведите его  в следующей строке (прибавляя 1). Да, это будет красиво, только для коротких строк (до 9 букв).

Comment: А что должно получиться, если есть одинаковые буквы? Одинаковый номер? Разные номера?

Comment: Такое я не предусматривал. К примеру по их порядку в слове. Какая буква первая в слове - та и нумеруется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

это код на C#, но ты должен его понять:

```
string message = "привет".ToLower();

Dictionary<int, char> d1 = new Dictionary<int, char>(message.Length);

foreach (char c in message)
{
    d1.Add(c - 'а', c);
}

Dictionary<int, char> d2 = new Dictionary<int, char>(message.Length);

int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 33; i++)
{
    char c;
    if (d1.TryGetValue(i,out c))
    {
        d2.Add(j, c);
        j++;
    }
}
```

нумерация идет с нуля, `j` отвечает за это
[image: скрин отладки]

Answer (score 1):

```
var message = "привет".ToLower();//привожу к одному виду
var en = message
    .Select(c => new {Ch = c, Value = c - 'а'})
    .OrderBy(v => v.Value)
    .GroupBy(v => v);//собираю перечисление с символом и его номером в алфавите
int i = 0;
var enumerable = en.Select(v => new {Ch = v.Key.Ch, Value = i++});//делаю номера последовательными

Dictionary<char, int> d = new Dictionary<char, int>(message.Length);
//элементы будут в словаре и ты легко сможешь сформировать результат в любом виде
foreach (var value in enumerable)
{
    d.Add(value.Ch, value.Value);
}
```

Comment: Это какой язык? Я должен это на простом си это выполнить...

Comment: упс! не обратил внимание. это C#

Answer (score 1):

Задачу можно решить через сортирующую перестановку для исходного массива букв (см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/935387/182825).

Сортирующая перестановка - это так называемая "from-перестановка", т.е. перестановка, которая говорит **из** какой позиции массива букв надо брать очередную букву, чтобы получить отсортированный массив.

Вам же нужна так называемая "to-перестановка", т.е. перестановка, которая для каждой буквы массива говорит, **в** какую позицию отсортированного массива попадет эта буква. Превратить "from-перестановку" в "to-перестановку" несложно

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static const char *s_string;

int cmp(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
  unsigned i1 = *(const unsigned *) p1, i2 = *(const unsigned *) p2;
  char c1 = s_string[i1], c2 = s_string[i2];
  return (c1 > c2) - (c1 < c2);
}

int main()
{
  const char *s = "dermatoglyphics";
  unsigned n = strlen(s);

  // Получаем from-перестановку
  unsigned from[n];
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    from[i] = i;

  s_string = s;
  qsort(from, n, sizeof *from, cmp);

  // Превращаем ее в to-перестановку
  unsigned to[n];
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    to[from[i]] = i;

  // Готово
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    printf("%u ", to[i] + 1);

  printf("\n");
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce0e851d3f06f26a

Comment: Я уже сделал почти рабочий вариант,но там есть одна проблема. Можете подсказать как исправить? Код и проблема в отредактированном вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

Простейший способ без сортировки - пройти n раз по строке, определяя на первом проходе минимальную букву, на втором - минимальную без учёт определённой на предыдущем шаге и так далее.

Comment: Проблема в том,что я не понимаю как это реализовать...

Comment: C помощью цикла for и сравнения if